# Jenkins pipeline with a sbt project

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have to write a pipeline code for jenkins using a sbt project. Normally I use Maven. I can't find the equivalent of withMaven for sbt projects. Do you know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no perfectly simple equivalent, since the sbt-plugin for jenkins haven't been ported to be pipeline-friendly.

The situation resumed in this ticket : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42475 is that there's a few possible ways to achieve that.

My prefered (aka the one similar to what we use in prod currently) is the last one :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'hseeberger/scala-sbt'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
                sh "sbt test"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

However, feel free to read through the ticket for other options, notably if docker is not an option for you, going for something like https://gist.github.com/muuki88/e2824008b653ac0fc5ba749fdf249616 should be quite ok too.

Comment: Sorry, but if I want to execute gatling, how I have to do? For an exemple, if I want replace this maven code: 

withMaven(globalMavenSettingsConfig: 'e0fb8527-8536-49dc-bfbd-ac98b5e85c2e', jdk: 'Default', maven: 'defaultMaven') {
 bat "sbt gatling:execute -Dgatling.simulationClass=it.aruba.tests.impl.LoadTestOne -Dusers=${params.users} -Dip=${params.ip}"
}

Comment: I have to execute gatling

Comment: Well, replace "sbt test" with whatever sbt command you want ^^